# RM output log with timestamp in crontab

Tags: shell, cron, timestamp, verbose

How can one timestamp the verbose flag when running RM in a crontab?

```
0 06 * * *  rm -v /somePath/FileToDelete > /somePath/filetoLog.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to call `date` explicitly:

```
0 06 * * *  (date && rm -v /somePath/FileToDelete) > /somePath/filetoLog.log
```

Comment: I tried this, but the logfile just say "removed". No date?

Comment: @miniHessel arg, forgot the parenthesis, so only the `rm` is redirected. Mea culpa - see my edited answer.

Comment: No success. Still just says removed. 

removed 'pathtoFile'

Comment: Started working now. Don't know if it was related to cache or something. Thanks!